# Jquery firing only once on dependant select dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are three dropdowns and two of them depend on first selection to appear. Once i select a value on the first dropdown which is called "category" the other two dropdowns become enabled however if i pick the empty value again on category the other two dropdown remain enabled.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("select").on("change", function() {
                if  ($("select[name='category']").val() == "") { 
                    $("select[name='subcategory']").attr("disabled");
                    $("select[name='name']").attr("disabled");
                } else {
                    $("select[name='subcategory']").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select[name='ename']").removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attributes vs. Properties**

> As of ***jQuery 1.6***, the [`.prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while `.attr()` retrieves attributes.

You can try using [**`.prop()`**](https://api.jquery.com/prop/):

```
.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
```

**Demo:** (As per the discussion in the comment)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select[name=category]").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") { 
      $("select[name=subcategory]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      $("select[name=ename]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');    
    } else {
      $("select[name=subcategory]").removeAttr("disabled");
      if($("select[name=subcategory]").val() == "") { 
        $("select[name=ename]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
      } else {
        $("select[name=ename]").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    }
    
  }).trigger('change');
  $("select[name=subcategory]").on("change", function() {
    if($(this).val() == "") { 
      $("select[name=ename]").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      $("select[name=ename]").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
  }).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="category">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select name="subcategory">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="a">A</option>
  <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
<select name="ename">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: On load other two are not remaining disable!

Comment: @BhavikKalariya, you are right, fixed that by triggering the *change* event, thanks:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208748/discussion-between-roni-x-and-mamun).

Comment: @RoniX, the updated code should work as you expect, please check:)